# Validation of AJAX submitted forms in Symfony 5

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I'm building an `Address` form in Symfony 5.1.

It is created in an `AddressType` Class that has some required fields.

```
$builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'label'  => 'address.name',
            'help' => 'address.name_help',
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => 'address.name_ph',
            ]
        ])
        ->add('company', TextType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'label'  => 'address.company',
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => 'address.company_ph',
            ]
        ])
        ->add('first_line', TextType::class, [
            'label'  => 'address.first_line',
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => 'address.first_line_ph',
            ]
        ])
        ->add('second_line', TextType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'label'  => 'address.second_line',
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => 'address.second_line_ph',
            ]
        ])
        ->add('add_info', TextType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'label'  => 'address.add_info',
            'help' => 'address.add_info_help',
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => 'address.add_info_ph',
            ]
        ])
        ->add('postcode', TextType::class, [
            'label'  => 'address.postcode',
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => 'address.postcode_ph',
            ]
        ])
        ->add('city', TextType::class, [
            'label'  => 'address.city',
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => 'address.city_ph',
            ]
        ])
        ->add('state', TextType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'label'  => 'address.state',
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => 'address.state_ph',
            ]
        ])
        ->add('country', CountryType::class, [
            'label'  => 'address.country',
            'preferred_choices' => ['FR'],
            'attr' => [
                'data-toggle' => 'select',
                'placeholder' => 'address.country_ph',
            ]
        ])
        ->add('save',
                SubmitType::class,
                [
                    'label'  => $options['submit_btn_label'],
                ]
            );
```

If I submit this form **with the submit button**, everything works as expected, my form is being processed for validation and if It detects some errors, they are shown on each field.

Here is the function that handle the form :

```
public function new(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $address = new Address();
    $address->setCreatedBy($user);
    $form = $this->createForm(AddressType::class, $address);
    //handle form
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted()){
        //if submit, add hidden fields
        $address = $form->getData();
        //if valid, process
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($address);
            $em->flush();   

            $this->addFlash(
                'success',
                'Your address was created.'
            );
            return $this->redirectToRoute('address_index');
        }
    } 
    return $this->render('address/new.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'mode' => 'new',
    ]);          
}
```

Now, If I submit this form **through an AJAX request** :

```
$(document).on('click', '.create-address', function() {
    console.log('submitting new address form...');
    var $form = $(this).closest('form')
    var data = $form.serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        url : $form.attr('action'),
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        data : data
    });
});
```

In this case, my form is processed for validation **and It passes** (`$form->isValid()` returns `true`) even if I don't provide some of the required fields.
This causes the process of persisting the object to occur and so I get a PDOException.

**My question is:**
Why is my form not handled the same way (especially at the validation step) according how I post the data ?
And how different are those two methods from the point of view of the function that handle the request ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`required` option](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#required) only adds the `required` attribute to the markup. This forces the browser to provide a value, but doesn't add any validation server side. You can [trigger validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#Validating_forms_using_JavaScript) before your ajax call and submit only if the form status is valid.

But it is recommended to add server side validation explicitly by using the `constraints` option in the form or annotating the target entity. Refer [to the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#constraints-in-form-classes) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for you answer @msg.
I understand the difference between a required attribute and a constraints. The entity `Address` is defined with some constraints, like not nullable.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood the difference between Constraints and ORM Rules in fact. (I had ORM rule for not nullable fields which is not sufficient/equivalent for validation I suppose).
Thanks

Comment: @Corentoulf I was going to ask just that. However, since 4.3 they should be [automatically generated](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-3-automatic-validation).

Comment: Hum.. So this is a strange behaviour right ? 
Adding a Constraint "forced" the validation anyway.

Comment: @Corentoulf I find it better to be explicit, so I'd normally add them anyways and not rely on that feature, so I can't tell you for sure, could be a regression. Can you check if you have the required dependency of `symfony/property-info` installed? (I think you should, it's just curiosity at this point).

Comment: It looks like a good practice indeed.
`symfony/property-info ` was installed but not up to date (5.0.8). Updating it to 5.1.8 didn't solve the issue anyway.